# What is the equivalent for apt-cacher-ng for windows?

Tags: windows, proxy, updates

What is the equivalent for [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/html/index.html) for using with Windows 7 machine? I have multiple Windows 7 machine and would like to keep the updates small and fast by keeping the updates within the LAN and let the other machines fetch from there.

Answer (score 3):

As far as it goes, the "Windows Software Update Service", which is available as part of server versions of Windows.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Software_Update_Services

It is more a "central distribution point and policy enforcement tool" though.

A standard Squid style proxy, or any other HTTP proxy, can go a long way with a little bit of tuning.  http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/WindowsUpdate

Comment: Thanks for the info - not sure if there is an easy way like say if I have a couple of Windows 7 machines at home.

Answer (score 2):

I use [wsus offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) - which downloads, and creates a 'repository' of sorts with the updates, and applies whats needed. Its perfect for small network use, and you can use it with most of the modern versions of windows and office.

I'd recommend running it with the 'copy products into selected directory' option, saving it to some location you can access on the computers in question (i've done it off a shared folder before - in which case don't use the automatic install and recall option) and running it

It does bypass the regular windows update method, so i primarily use it for one off updating, but it should work for a poor man's WSUS replacement when run on an external USB or shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

See this [HowTo](http://www.wuinstall.com/index.php/en/pro/40-news/48-cache) of WuInstall Caching Updates, maybe this helps you. There is also a link to a youtube video demonstrating how it works.

However, your machines need to have internet connection to fetch the list of updates, the updates themselves can then be loaded via LAN from a shard directory, so bandwith is minimized.